# How to delete the element in a list which is duplicated for linear representation in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, replace

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aNJs.jpg

I want to draw an evolution diagram like this, `[1,2,3,4]` is an annotation to the point:

```
1 :(x=1,y=2)
2 :(x=2,y=3)
3 :(x=3,y=5)
4 :(x=4,y=6)
```

The connection is like:

```
a = [1,1,2,3] *Starting Point
b = [2,4,4,4] *Ending Point
```

And because point1 and point2 both connect to point4 and I don't want the connection of point to point4 because point1 evolved to point2 first.
So I want to get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yV8n.jpg

```
c = [1,2,3]
d = [2,4,4]
```

I tried to use `zip` to write a for loop but it failed.

How to get `c` and `d` in python?

Comment: Sorry don't understand how you are calculating the need to delete `1, 4` and `2, 4` from `1, 2`

Comment: Because `3` connected to `4` and `1` , `2` connected to 3, so I didn't want the connection of `1` and `2` to `4`, I only wanted `1` to `2`, `2` to `3` and `3` to `4`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand it looks like you are looking for a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) for the graph where the edges are (a_i,b_i). You can do this as follows:

```
A = sp.sparse.csr_matrix((len(a),len(a)),dtype='bool')
A[a,b] = 1
c,d = sp.sparse.csgraph.minimum_spanning_tree(A).nonzero()
```

Note that the minimum spanning tree is not unique.

Comment: Thanks! But actually what I wanted is maximum weight of `a` connected to `b`, the result of minimum spanning tree wasn't match the result I wanted. Is there any kind of algorithm can solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe if you post another example it will be more clear what you are looking for. For instance, why do you delete 1,4 and 2,4 instead of 1,4 and 3,4 or 1,2 and 4,3? Is it because the come first in your list? I.e., if you reordered `a` and `b` would your result be the same or not?

Comment: @wayne64001 what do you mean 'weight', if these are just edges in an undirected graph, how are you determining the weight. BTW There are multiple minimum spanning trees possible.